# Berkshelf loading wrong dependencies

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant, berkshelf

I'm trying to create a cookbook to install my developemnt environment in vagrant.
I am using **vagrant 1.4.3** over **OSX 10.9** and **Berkshelf 2.0.13**.
The cookbook I'm developing is in github (https://github.com/Batou99/console-development)

When I run berks install inside my cookbook folder everything is fine, berkshelf downloads the right dependencies, I am specially interested in 7even/oh-my-zsh which berkshelf downloads just fine.

But when I use my new cookbook in a vagrant machine I want to provision, I load my cookbook in the Berksfile using

**cookbook 'console-development', git: 'http://github.com/Batou99/console-development'**

But somehow berkshelf ends up loading the oh-my-zsh cookbook stored in opscode which is completely different.

What am I doing wrong? Why berkshelf ignores the path I set in my cookbook?

I've been trying to fix this for several hours and its driving me crazy, any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue with Berkshelf. For a full list of open issues, please see: https://github.com/berkshelf/berkshelf/issues